# Running Opencv Python code on Odroid (linux) with ROS kinetic: X11 error

Tags: linux, opencv, x11, odroid

On running a image processing algorithm on Odroid having ROS kinetic installed is unable to run.  It shows an x11 error. I have tried to reset the x11 config but it doesn't seem to work. I am seriously stuck in my project.

`root@odroid:~# python image_detection.py`

```
The X11 connection broke: Unsupported extension used (code 2)
XIO:  fatal IO error 22 (Invalid argument) on X server "localhost:10.0"
      after 6 requests (6 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: Seems like you're using an unsupported extension and accessing an illegal memory location..

Comment: Actually I have narrowed it to an error. When I run the code with cv2.imshow() the program doesn't run. But without that line, things work fine. I guess x11 isn't allowing the imshow to pop up on the ssh.